# How to store other languages in mysql database using ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I want to store languages other than English in MySQL database using Ruby. I've tried to store `Hindi` language characters in MySQL database, but got `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error. Here is the attached screenshot -

[image: error screenshot]

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the following command on your desired table(s):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) on collation and character set configuration.

Hope it helps!